# Why I can set gif as background image url() in css, but can't set video mp4 as background url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

Why I can set gif as background image url() in css, but can't set video mp4 as background url?

I tried everything, even setting url to point to svg that has foreign object video in it encoded as base64 in src attribute. But won't work.

I don't need video bcg as video element in html, i need exactly that as i can blur the content of the children using inherit background and before selector.

Comment: Are you expecting video to be played when set at CSS `url()`?

Comment: yes exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the video playback at CSS `url()` by playing the media at `<video>` element, drawing the playing video at `<canvas>`  element and calling `.toDataURL()` to set `background` of element to `data URI` at `timeupdate` event of `<video>` element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <script>
    (async() => {

      let div = document.querySelector("div");

      let url = "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=10,20";

      let video = document.createElement("video");

      let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      video.oncanplay = function() {
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        div.style.width = video.videoWidth + "px";
        div.style.height = video.videoHeight + "px";
        this.play();
      }

      video.ontimeupdate = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        let dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
        div.style.background = `url(${dataURI})`;
        
      }

      let mediaBlob = await fetch(url).then(response => response.blob());

      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaBlob);

    })()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Alexa You can alternatively substitute `requestAnimationFrame` for `timeupdate` event to draw `data URI` at CSS `url()` function.

Comment: this is Amazing! tnx!

Comment: sadly, i only get 8fps on this video, on high quality video is not playable

Comment: Have you tried substituting `requestAnimationFrame` for `timeupdate` event of `<video>` element?

Comment: Are you trying to display HTML content overlay at the video playback at `<video>` element, for example, captions or subtitles?

Comment: I am just changing backgroundImage of body element every frame. If image is of hig quality it want be playable. Body has few children elements that have background inherited from body and before selectors on that elements have also background inherited from body and have blur filter on it.

Answer (score 3):

CSS background and background-image properties only accept colours, gradients, bitmaps and SVG as values.

We can create a simple HTML5 video element and place it inside a container element. The image used in a poster attribute will be showed first, and then be replaced by the first frame of the video when it loads. Therefore it’s good practice to use the first frame of a video for a poster image.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox implements CSS [`element()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#funcdef-element) function, which allows for example a `<canvas>` element to be set at `background` or `background-image` property using [`-moz-element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) or [`Document.mozSetImageElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element)

> The `element()` CSS function defines an [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image) value generated
>   from an arbitrary HTML element. This image is live, meaning that if
>   the HTML element is changed, the CSS properties using the resulting
>   value are automatically updated.

We can use `.drawImage()` and `requestAnimationFrame()` to draw the `<video>` onto the `<canvas>` see [html5: display video inside canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas), [Drawing video on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079583/drawing-video-on-canvas),  which render a live feed of the `<video>` playback at for example a `<div>` element CSS `background-image` property.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const video = document.createElement("video");
video.id = "video";
canvas.id = "canvas";
canvas.style.display = "none";
canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 280;
div.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
div.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

let raf;

const draw = () => {
  if (video.paused || video.ended) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    return;
  }

  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 280);

  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

video.oncanplay = () => {
  if ("mozSetImageElement" in document) {
    div.style.backgroundImage = "-moz-element(#canvas)";
    video.play();
    draw();
  }
}

video.src = "https://meeseeks.gamepedia.com/media/meeseeks.gamepedia.com/a/a6/Big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm";
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  div element
</div>
```

Comment: I eventually done it with canvas(has support for filters). Every element that needs to blur background which  is video has child canvas which has position fixed. On that canvas I draw blured image every 4 frame. Parent has css clip path property which hides owerflow because position fixed does not allow parent to hide overflow.
https://miketaylr.com/posts/2015/06/position-fixed-overflow-hidden.html
tnx

Answer (score 1):

Here's some video background code that worked for me:

in the html:

```
 <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
    <source src="<yourvideo>" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

and in css:

```
    #video-background {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 75%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for video in bg you should use *video* tag in html5!

here is the fullscrean video code:

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="video/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

and few simple lines of CSS:

```
.fullscreen-bg { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -100; } .fullscreen-bg__video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

source: https://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/